# Change right to left rectangle fit action to match left to right zoom

Tags: lightningchart

I would like to change the right to left rectangle mouse drag functionality in a ChartXY object. By default a right to left drag will zoom out and fit all data, while showing an 'x' in the rectangle area. I would prefer this drag to simple be a zoom in, the same way as dragging left to right. This matches most other graphing libraries, and it will help people use LC without learning a new mouse interaction strategy.

Ive scoured the forums and API and surprisingly havn't found a straight forward solution. I would have expected this to be a relatively straight forward configuration change, but Im struggling to find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Bala

Ive looked through all of the ChartXY and Xaxis and Yaxis properties and methods, and have not found anything obvious. I have looked through every form post and example I could find, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want the rectangle zoom interaction to work regardless of mouse direction (left to right, right to left, whatever).

Currently the direction separates the functionality to two very different interactions (zoom, fit).

There is no built-in method for achieving this right now.
However, I would see this as a very simple improvement we can add and it even happens that we have a new version release shipping out tomorrow so I'll try to get this included in there.

The default behavior will be unchanged, but if user disables the built-in rectangle zoom to fit interaction (right to left) using `chart.setMouseInteractionRectangleFit(false)` then we can use fallback to zooming regardless of the direction.

Comment: Hello @niilo-keinänen that would be amazing! Looking forward to seeing this.

I have set up a workaround to zoom depending on mouse drag events, but now the problem is the left drag is still registered as a fill type, so I have to style it using ChartXY.setFittingRectangleStrokeStyle(), where I would prefer if it would simply follow the same stroke style as the right drag zoom rectangle Stroke style.

Let me know if/when you are able to get this change in. Thanks!!

Comment: Woops, meant to say the left drag is still registered as a fitting rectangle, instead of a zoom rectangle, and so I have to style it using the setFittingRectangleStrokeStyle() even though it is now zooming in with my event handler.

Comment: The mentioned library side change has been included in v5.1 release content, which should be rolling out to NPM in a few hours. This was a good little improvement, so thank you for opening the thread and articulating the issue clearly.